# Remove quick action box

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a lightning component and have it set as a quick action. However, I do not want the quick action box to appear. I want a button placed where the other quick action buttons are hence why I placed my lc in a quick action.

Cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="apexclass" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" /> 
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

  <aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.doneRendering}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isDoneRendering" type="Boolean" default="false"/>     

</aura:component>
```

JS Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.updateField");
        action.setParams({
            oppID: component.get("v.recordId")
        });
         action.setCallback(this, function(response)
                              {
                                var state = response.getState();
                                             if (state == "SUCCESS") {
                                                console.log('success');
                                             }
                                  else {
                                      console.log('something went wrong');
                                       }
                              });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);       

    },

    doneRendering: function(component, event, helper) {
    if(!component.get("v.isDoneRendering")){
        var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire(); 

         var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                                                 toastEvent.setParams({
                                                     mode: 'sticky',
                                                     type:'success',
                                                     "title": "Success!",
                                                     "message": "It works"
                                                 });
                                                 toastEvent.fire();
    }
     else{
         alert('attribute is true.');
     } 
      //reset isDoneRendering attribute to false for the next time code is used
      component.set("v.isDoneRendering", false);  
    },      

 })
```

As you can see I use e.force:closeQuickAction to close the quick action however, it still appears for half a second. Is it possible to stop it rendering completely. Like I said above, I only want my LC as a button along with the other quick actions so the only way I know how to do this is set a quick action to my lc.

Comment: Nope. This has already been asked before, too, but I can't seem to find it. You have to deal with the limitations. You might want to [submit an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) for this.